# "Access violation reading location 0x00000000" GDAL WKT C++

Tags: c++, qt, gdal, wkt

I work on GIS-system and use database for storing coordinates. I read coordinates from database with QT API. I get coordinates from database in WKT format (Well-Known Text). Next, I'm trying to build GDAL types (OGRGeometry) from WKT. Geometry is abstract class, and Point inherits Geometry. I'm trying to use function, special for Point. And when I'm debugging, there is error in final column. The erros is ""Access violation reading location 0x00000000""

```
`QString qsWKT = model.data(model.index(0, 0)).toString();
std::string temp(qpszWKT.toStdString()); 
char* pszWkt = (char*)temp.c_str();
OGRGeometry* new_geom;
OGRErr err = OGRGeometryFactory::createFromWkt(&pszWkt, NULL, &new_geom);
if(new_geom->getGeometryName() == "Point") { qDebug() << "good";}`
```

Comment: string.c_str() returns const char*, you cast it to char*, and then use the char* variable in function createFromWkt; this looks suspicious.

Comment: The cast is probably not what's causing the code to try to read from NULL, though.

Comment: Why don't you check  `err` before getting an access to created `new_geom`? I am sure, `err` will inform you about real reason of problem. Also it is better to initialize pointers to avoid undefined behaviour (i.e. `OGRGeometry* new_geom = 0;`). And check pointer before dereferencing (i.e. `if (new_geom) if(new_geom->getGeometryName() == "Point") {...}`).

Comment: I checked and    err = OGRERR_NONE, i.e. it isn't reason of trouble. Next, I initialized pointer, but I still have this error.

Comment: @Andrew Medico, yes. I checked and pointer is NULL. Why, I don't understand. Because createFromWkt must changed this pointer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs of `OGRGeometryFactory::createFromWkt`](https://web.archive.org/web/20180717194235/http://www.gdal.org:80/classOGRGeometryFactory.html#a9418f71bcfb1e334173882c38d89d070) (found with Google), your `new_geom` *"will be NULL if the method fails"*.

Now if you are getting return value `OGRERR_NONE` but also that `NULL`, then there are a few possiblitities:

1. The code where you checked return value is wrong (not shown in the question).
2. There's bug in the library.
3. There's some undocumented error situation, where you get combination of that `NULL` but also `OGRERR_NONE` return value.

Which ever of these it is, you must still check if you get that `NULL`, and interpret it as an unspecified error.

---

Then the question becomes, why do you get the error. I suggest you add these debug prints:

```
qDebug() << "qsWKT:" << qsWKT;
qDebug() << "hexdump:" << QByteArray(pszWKT).toHex();
```

Then look at those and try to figure out if you have some of these:

- just plain invalid WKT format
- unexpected whitespace (use `QString::trimmed()` or even `QString::simplified()` to fix)
- text encoding mismatch in the original data before it's converted to `QString` UTF16
- text encoding mismatch when converting from `QString` to `std::string`

WKT should probably be 7-bit ASCII, so if that hex dump shows any values which are `>= 0x80`, then you know for sure you have an encoding or data corruption problem.